# c Programming: execvp() call always returning false

Tags: c, shell, process, exec, execvp

I am trying to write a simple shell program. I take a user input via getline(), and tokenize that string - I keep the arguments in a char* arg[]; execvp, however, never works and always returns a neg. number.

CODE:

```
char* arg[100];
int i = 0;
for (i; i<100; i++){
    arg[i] = malloc(11); //each one has 11 bytes
}

tokenize();

i = 0;
for (i; i<100; i++){
    printf("Arg %d: %s\n", i, arg[i]);
}

pid_t child = -5;
child = fork();

if (child == 0){
    if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0){
        printf("Failed.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

RUNNING:

```
ls
```

OUTPUT:

```
Arg 0: ls
Arg 1:
Arg 2:
....
Failed.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) that demonstrates the problem.  You don't demonstrate that there's a null pointer (not an empty string) after the last argument.  Your printing loop should stop when `arg[i] == NULL`, and you should ensure that there is a null pointer there.  Note too that error should be preinted on the standard error file stream — `stderr`.  Also note that there's no need to test the return value from `execvp()`; if it returns, it failed.

Comment: Printing out a more useful message on error would doubtlessly be useful. Read up on `errno`, `perror()`, and `strerror()`.

Comment: Jonathan, that's interesting. That's where the error is, then: I need to ensure that after the last argument, there is a NULL pointer. I'll work on this and get back to you with my results. Thank you. EDIT: Got it. Thanks once again.

Comment: regarding: `if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0){
        printf("Failed.\n");`  this should be: `execvp( arg[0], arg );  perror( "execvp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAULURE );

Comment: the function : fork()` has three kinds of returned values (<0 means an error occurred) (==0 means the child process is executing) (>0 means the parent process is executing )  Each of these conditions need to be checked for and handled.  Note: when the parent process is executing, it must call `wait()` to wait until the child process has exited

Comment: OT: regarding: `pid_t child = -5;
child = fork();`  this just clutters the code, suggest: `pid_t child = fork();`

Comment: suggest replacing: `for (i; i<100; i++){
    arg[i] = malloc(11);` with `for (i; i<100; i++){
    arg[i] = calloc(11, 1);`  so any unused arguments will already be set to NULL.  This also means can only have a total of 99 arguments so there is always a trailing NULL in the list of arguments